# How to keep the navigation controller after clicking on a container view to show?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uicontainerview

I have a problem keeping the navigation controller in place I have a `ViewController` that has a container view holding a `TableViewController`. Now when I click on a row in the `TableViewController` to navigate to another `ViewController` it does not contain the navigation controller for me to go back.

Below is a picture example:

```
+---------------------------------+
|                                 |
|     UINavigationBar             |
|                                 |        +------------------------+
+---------------------------------+        |                        |
|   +------------------------+    |        |                        |
|   |                        |    |        |                        |
|   |                        |    |--------|                        |
|   |                        |    | embeded|  UITableViewController |
|   |                        |    |   segue|                        | 
|   |UITableViewController   |    |        |                        |
|   |   in a container view  |    |        |                        |
|   |                        |    |        +------------------------+
|   +------------------------+    |                    |
|                                 |                    |
|                                 |                    |
|           UIViewController      |                    | show Detail segue
|                                 |                    | present modal segue
|                                 |                    | 
+---------------------------------+                    |
                                                       |
                                        +---------------------------------+
                                        |                                 |
                                        |                                 | 
                                        |                                 |
                                        |                                 |
                                        |                                 |
                                        |          UIViewController       | 
                                        |                                 |
                                        |                                 |
                                        |                                 |
                                        |                                 |
                                        |                                 |
                                        |                                 |
                                        +---------------------------------+
```

The last `ViewController` does not have the `Navigation controller` passed to it and additionally just to mention that the show segue doesn't work because it clips the `ViewController` to the same size as the container view so I had to use show detail or present modally to keep the right size.

So overall I am just trying to get the navigation controller to appear on the final `ViewController` so I can go back.

Thanks in advance for any help at all.

**EDITED:** **BELOW IS AN IMAGE OF WHAT HAPPENS IF I USE SHOW**

[image]

Comment: Is it necessary to have the extra indirection of the embedded vc?  In other words, can you just place a UITableView subview on the initial view controller's view, making it the delegate?  This is simpler, and will make it straight forward to do a push (optionally via a push segue) to the second UIViewController.

Comment: @danh thanks for the reply, I have a map view below the containerview which I didn't mention, I think that's the reason I used containerview to embed. Not sure if subviewing the UItableview would be the better solution in this case. What is your opinion on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think both the map view and table views can (probably should) be simple sub views of the first vc's view.

Comment: Can you link me to any examples of this as I have been using containerviews when I need to deal with multiple controllers. Not quite familiar to subviewing. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you present modally then the navigationcontroller will be gone. If you want to have the exact same navigationcontroller with an automatic back-button you simply need to use a push-segue and not a modal one.

Modal segues come up from the bottom and they need their own navigationcontroller, and also then you'd need to add your own backbutton as the top left navigation barbuttonitem.

Comment: thanks for the reply, however push is deprecated now and replaced with show. However using show it crops my viewcontroller to the size of the container view. I used show detail which seems to be fine in terms of size but still no navigation controller.

Comment: Hi, push is indeed deprecated but if you use 'show' it should not present modally. That's only if you set it to 'present modally'. How does it animate? From the bottom up?

Comment: As I mentioned "show" crops my view into a small box that matches the container view  which is unusable. I am not using "present modally" at the moment, I am using "show detail" now. I put "present modally" and "show detail" in the diagram to show that only both of these work that doesn't affect my layout.

Comment: Hm, do you actually have a navigationcontroller in your storyboard as well!? Or only a viewcontroller with a navigationbar?

Comment: I have the navigationviewcontroller.

Comment: @Tony.C This is all very weird, could you upload a screenshot of your storyboard?

Comment: i have added the image

Comment: @Tony.C In your image I don't see the navigationviewcontroller with a segue to your venuesportsviewcontrolller. So I think this is the issue..

Comment: @Tony.C The venuesportsviewcontroller doesn't look like a containerview, it has it's own status bar at the top. That doesn't happen with containerviews...

Comment: my bad I meant the VenueSportsTableView is a containerview. I do have a navigationveiwcontroller but I didn't take a snapshot of it. I just showed where the navigationviewcontroller no longer woreks.

Comment: @Tony.C I unfortunately can't help you without more information. Right now it seems venusportsviewcontroller is not a containerview but I can't see the whole storyboard...